# What is the "aviation-culture" tag for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have a [aviation-culture](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation-culture) with 7 questions.

3 of them are closed, with a 4th that probably need migration.

The other 3 do not seem to be needing such a tag, imho.

What is this tag for? Do we need it or do we want to burninate / ban it?

Comment: It's self-evident that the "aviation-culture" tag is for flying things found in petri dishes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that:

- half are closed
- very low number
- no excerpt/wiki re usage guidance
- open to interpretation:

  - [Organisational Culture](https://skybrary.aero/articles/organisational-culture)? (skybrary.aero)
  - [Safety Culture](https://skybrary.aero/articles/safety-culture)? (skybrary.aero)
  - movies?

> Retiring the tag is the way to go.